# loading html table from an array in javascript loaded with data from parse.com

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, parse-platform

I need to create a table in HTML dinamically using javascrit, I have some arrays that I filled with data from Parse.com

like this

```
var Prog = Parse.Object.extend("Programmation");
            var queryProg = new Parse.Query(Prog);
            queryProg.find({
                success: function (prog) {
                    for (i = 0; i < prog.length; i++) {
                        programmationArray.push({
                            idExam: prog[i].get("IdExam"),
                            idLocation: prog[i].get("IdLocation"),
                            idGroup: prog[i].get("IdGroup"),
                            programmedDate: prog[i].get("Date"),
                            //id: prog[i].get("objectId")
                            id: prog[i].id
                        });
                    }
                    fillTable(groupsArray, locationsArray, examsArray, programmationArray);

                },
                error: function (object, error) {
                    alert("Error loading data for Programmed Exams")
                }
            });
```

Then after I have filled all my arrays I call the function fillTable()...

```
  function fillTable(groupsArray, locationsArray, examsArray, programmationArray) {
            var mytable = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
            for (k in programmationArray) {
                var result2 = programmationArray[k];
                var myrow = mytable.insertRow(k);
                var cell1 = myrow.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = myrow.insertCell(1);
                var cell3 = myrow.insertCell(2);
                var cell4 = myrow.insertCell(3);

                for (x in groupsArray) {
                    var result = groupsArray[x];
                    if (result.groupId == result2.idGroup) {
                        cell1.innerHTML = result.groupDescription;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                for (y in locationsArray) {
                    var resultloc = locationsArray[y];
                    if (resultloc.locId == result2.idLocation) {
                        cell2.innerHTML = resultloc.locDescription;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                for (z in examsArray) {
                    var resultExam = examsArray[z];
                    if (resultExam.examId == result2.idExam) {
                        cell3.innerHTML = resultExam.examDescription;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                cell4.innerHTML = formatedDate(result2.programmedDate);


                }
            }
```

Everything works fine but, when the load is finished sometimes the table, has some columns EMPTY, when I reload the page, shows the missed columns, but hides another, and sometimes load the whole table fine... I would like that always shows all the data (not only sometimes)

I attach a picture, where did not load the whole table

[the image shows that data from groups was not loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZk8f.png)

Answer (score 0):

Couple things I can see...

1) In general you shouldn't use `for(x in array)` to iterate over arrays.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

> Array indexes are just enumerable properties with integer names and are
>   otherwise identical to general Object properties. There is no
>   guarantee that for...in will return the indexes in any particular
>   order and it will return all enumerable properties, including those
>   with non–integer names and those that are inherited.
>
> Because the order of iteration is implementation-dependent, iterating
>   over an array may not visit elements in a consistent order. Therefore
>   it is better to use a for loop with a numeric index (or
>   Array.prototype.forEach() or the for...of loop) when iterating over
>   arrays where the order of access is important.

Specifically I'm guessing that this is the issue "including those with non–integer names and those that are inherited" if the parse.com objects inherit in unanticipated ways, this could cause false matches for you in your internal loops.

2) with your `break;` you are exiting your loop, so I'd make sure your break condition is finding the right item in the array (see #3). You might also want to consider the `find` method (available in [ES6 or via a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)) for readability.

3) when checking for equality, try to use the identity operator `===` which will check for value and type equality. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity

4) instead of `.innerHTML` look into using `.textContent` to fill in the value of your cells. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

> innerHTML returns the HTML as its name indicates. Quite often, in
>   order to retrieve or write text within an element, people use
>   innerHTML. textContent should be used instead. Because the text is not
>   parsed as HTML, it's likely to have better performance. Moreover, this
>   avoids an XSS attack vector.